# Type of payload in dispatch then

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have thunk, that returns some `FirstOffers` type.

When i use it in extraReducesr all is ok

```
builder.addCase(getFirstOffers.fulfilled, (state, {payload} <- type of payload is FirstOffers) => {...}
```

And i need to get value in then of dispatch, but in then type of payload is unknown

```
 dispatch(getFirstOffers()).then(({payload} <- type of payload is unknown) => {...});
```

Unexpected behavior for me and `PayloadAction<FirstOffers>` doesn't help

body of action `getFirstOffers`

```
export const getFirstOffers = createAsyncThunk<FirstOffers, number | undefined>(
  `${FIRST_OFFERS_SLICE_NAME}/getFirstOffers`,
  async (count = 10) => {
    const response = await axios.post<Response<FirstOffers>>(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/getFirstOffers`,
      `count=${count}`,
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      },
    );

    return response.data.response;
  },
);
```